# Something strainge on Thread and Runnable

Tags: java, multithreading

As we all know, Thread cannot share the class resource but Runnable can.
But there is something confusing that Thread could achieve the previous purpose with ThreadPool.

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

class TestThread extends Thread {
    private int val = 10;
    public void run(){
        while(true){
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread() + "-- val: " + val--);
            Thread.yield();
            if  (val <= 0)
                return;
        }
    }
}

class TestRunnable implements Runnable {
    private int val = 10;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true){
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread() + "-- val: " + val--);
            Thread.yield();
            if (val <= 0)
                return;
        }
    }    
}

public class TestRunnableAndThread {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Runnable runnable = new TestRunnable();
        Thread thread = new TestThread();
        // a.1 thread, 1 data
        thread.start();
        thread.start();
        thread.start();
        thread.start();
        thread.start();
        // b.5 threads, 5 data
        new TestThread().start();
        new TestThread().start();
        new TestThread().start();
        new TestThread().start();
        new TestThread().start();
        // c.5 threads, 1 data
        new Thread(runnable).start();
        new Thread(runnable).start();
        new Thread(runnable).start();
        new Thread(runnable).start();
        new Thread(runnable).start();
        // d.5 threads, 1 data
        ExecutorService execRun = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            execRun.execute(runnable);
        // e.5 threads, 5 data
        ExecutorService execRun2 = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            execRun2.execute(new TestRunnable());
        // f.5 threads, 1 data
        ExecutorService execThread = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            execThread.execute(thread);
        }
        // g.5 threads, 5 data
        ExecutorService execThread2 = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            execThread2.execute(new TestThread());
        // i.5 threads, 1 data
        ExecutorService execThread2 = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            execThread2.execute(new Thread(runnable));

        execRun.shutdown();
        execRun2.shutdown();
        execThread.shutdown();
        execThread2.shutdown();
    }
}
```

c、d and i produce the same effects, b and g produce the same effects, but a and f should be the same in theory, but they didn't.
Is that means Thread can share the class resource? I cannot understand that clearly.

Comment: "As we all know, Thread cannot share the class resource but Runnable can." Do we all know that? Do we all know what that even means? I don't... Please explain.

Comment: Giving the same (stateful) `Runnable` instance to more than one thread as you do in (c) and (d) is highly confusing. Ideally, a runnable should only have some `final` configuration and keep any runtime state only as local variables inside of `run`. If you want to share some mutable data across multiple threads, better put it into an external object (that you can pass to your runnables in their constructors). And that data-carrier needs to be thread-safe.

Comment: `runnable`, instance of `TestRunnable`, is run mutliple times concurrently. That means the field `val`will be modified from different concurrent threads. It won't work reliable. You should use a synchronisation mechanism to share variable across threads.

Comment: Also, `Thread thread = new TestThread(); thread.start(); thread.start();` is illegal. You can't keep starting the same thread, you get `IllegalThreadStateException`.

Comment: Giving a `Thread` to `executorService.execute` is also highly confusing. The executor will only use that as a `Runnable`, it will not do anything with the thread (it will call `run()` on one of its own threads instead).

Comment: Re, "Thread cannot...but Runnable can." `Runnable` can't _do_ anything. `Runnable` is nothing but an interface.  That is, it's a specification of a method that _you_ must provide when _you_ define a class that `implements Runnable`.

Comment: Don't call `Thread.yield()`. It won't do anything useful in a modern, general-purpose Java runtime environment.  In fact, if you read the documentation, you will see that it is not _required_ to do anything at all.

Comment: @Thilo I'm so sorry about my inaccurate description, "As we all know, ... but Runnable can." I got it from some blogs, but I haven't verified it. In fact, I also didn't understand what it means. So usually are sharing data expected to be stored in an external and thread-safe object instead of a class attribute？

Comment: @Thilo  and what parameter does `executorService.execute` usually require, a `Runnable` or a `Thread`? Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: @Solomon Slow   Thanks, I read the source code, "A hint to the scheduler that the current thread is willing to yield its current use of a processor. The scheduler is free to ignore this hint." So would it do nothing? Or would it do nothing just sometimes?

Comment: You can refer to the JavaDoc for ExecutorService. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html  Submit takes a Runnable or a Callable. The ExecutorService takes care of providing the thread to execute those.